# Nested Tests with JUnit 5 and Spring Boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I am trying to write some nested integration tests for an application which I am building.

The tests are building up on each other and should test if the whole work flow is working as expected.

I tried doing it as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class XMLTest {

    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() {

        // Initialize some things
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("testA")
    class testA {

        @Test
        public void testGettingSomething() {
            ... test something ...
        }

        @Nested
        @DisplayName("testB")
        class testB {

            @Test
            public void testSomethingElse() {
                ... test something else ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I always get the error

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods at 
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>
```

I think I read that the `@Nested` annotation is from `JUnit 5`, while it seems that `Spring` wants to use a `JUnit 4 runner`. Could this be the error? And if so, how can I tell Spring to use a `JUnit 5 runner`?

**EDIT 1**
I removed the `RunWith(...)` annotation and that fixed that error, but now I got another one:

[image: Tests not found]

This seems like an odd error, since [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) pointed out that runners are a concept of JUnit 4. Or am I confusing something here?

**EDIT 2**

Here's the list of dependencies:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-spring:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:8.3.1:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO]    org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:jar:1.3.0.gg2:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:8.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin.external:gentyref:jar:1.2.0.vaadin1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:8.3.1:compile
[INFO]    com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar:8.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO]    net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO]    org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.14.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO]    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:runtime
[INFO]    com.jysk.dbl:common:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    org.vaadin.spring.addons:vaadin-spring-addon-eventbus:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.jysk.dbl:common-security:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO]    org.vaadin.spring.extensions:vaadin-spring-ext-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.vaadin.spring.extensions:vaadin-spring-ext-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.vaadin.spring.extensions:vaadin-spring-ext-security:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.jysk.dbl:common-selenium:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.6-jre:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO]    com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO]    com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.8.0-11:compile
[INFO]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.45:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.14-kohsuke-1:compile
[INFO]    javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO]    org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO]    org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.1.0:test
```

The relevant ones should be at the bottom.

Comment: Please let us know exactly which versions of JUnit 5 artifacts are in your classpath, preferably by providing your Maven or Gradle build configuration.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of Eclipse (see [JUnit 5 setup and version requirements](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-setup/#IDE-Support))? Do you have the same problem when running tests with a build tool? (Please add these information to your question.)

Comment: @SamBrannen I edited my question and included my classpath.

Comment: @Nicolai Yes, I am using `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)`. When running with build tools, it simply skips the class with no output whatsoever. (Which makes sense since it thinks the class has no test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incompatible versions of JUnit artifacts in the classpath.

```
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.1.0:test
```

You need to ensure that you are using Jupiter 5.3.1 and Platform 1.3.1 consistently for all of your JUnit 5 artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

The `@RunWith` annotation and the concept of runners come from JUnit 4. Just lose that line (but keep the `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` line!) and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It fixed this error, but now I got another. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @Niby94 do you have any methods annotated with `@Test` there? The code snippet you shared doesn't show any.

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll some methods to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Could it be that your `@Test` annotations come from JUnit 4? Unless this is an existing project that has lots of JUnit 4 tests, you should exclude the dependencies on JUnit 4, so these errors can no longer happen.

Comment: @Nicolai No, they are from the `org.junit.jupiter.api` package.